# Track Amazon Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a c1.medium machine.  Once in a while, the machine becomes unresponsive.  Is there a way to detect this?

My initial solution was to write a simple script which pings this machine every hour.  But, this failed because, it was able to ping, yet was unresponsive(really weird!).

Is there a better way to monitor this?

Comment: Did you try Amazon CloudWatch? Or are you looking for something service specific?

Comment: I am looking for something very simple.

Comment: +1 for Cloudwatch is about as simple as it gets? If you have sysstat installed you might want to check sar for the times it became unresponsive in case the iowait is very high. This is the usual ec2 bottleneck.

Comment: In my experience it is steal that is the usual ec2 bottleneck, probably because I am using micro instances.  :)  On a more helpful note, with the default amazon Linux image I had to install sysstat.i386 to get sar.

Answer (score 0):

then you have to define what unresponsive means. If unresponsive on http port(80) you can probe that specific port - the instance might be up but the process dead.